# LogicApps SFTP SSH Issue

Tags: azure, sftp, azure-logic-apps

I would like to ask for the issue encountered below using an SFTP-SSH Connector in LogicApps. There are no errors when creating the connection but when running the LogicApp, I am getting the error below.

```
        "message": "BadGateway",
        "innerError": {
            "status": 502,
            "message": "openssh key type: ssh-rsa is not supported\r\nclientRequestId: 83dbd131-dcb3-41ca-b833-8d617222f4a4",
            "error": {
                "message": "openssh key type: ssh-rsa is not supported"
            },
            "source": "sftpwithssh-ne.azconn-ne.p.azurewebsites.net"
        }
```

Can you let me know what needs to be done in order to successfully establish connection in LogicApps with the SFTP server?

Thanks!